# Anaconda - is using channel conda-forge screwing up the whole environment?

Tags: python, anaconda, conda

I've been having some issues recently using the navigator as well as Conda for installing/updating modules. Researching around a bit has suggested that adding/removing channels solves certain issues. For example, running `ipython` from the terminal gave me an error of missing modules for `beakerx`. So I decided to install it since its also requred by JupyterLab. However, a simple `conda install beakerx` wouldn't work with the `anaconda-fusion` channel that comes as default primary.

I found out that `conda-forge` is the go-to channel so I thought I might add it from the terminal. Now, when I launch the navigator, it kind of messes up the home screen, like so:

[image: Image_1]

Whereas restarting the navigator after setting `anaconda-fusion` as the default channel, the home screen looked more normal:

[image: Image_2]

Also notice the first image has `Orange 3` and `Glue` as being shown as outdated, whereas in the second image, no such updates are shown. Is there a way I could clean up the mess `conda-forge` creates since I would prefer using that instead of `anaconda-fusion`?

Answer (score 1):

Never mind lack of answers to my question. I changed back the channel to the default `anaconda-fusion` and updated some libraries that were instead not showing up on the environments tab. Removed `conda-forge` to bring back normal startup. While updating certain libraries, `conda-forge` is automatically selected as a higher priority channel.